# Changing the length of a line renderer using DOTween

Tags: unity-game-engine, tween, dotween

I am trying to change the length of my line renderer over time using DOTween.

```
LineRenderer myLineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
myLineRenderer.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(x, 0, 0));
```

This code snippet changes the position of myLineRenderer to `x`. How can I use DOTween to set the position *gradually* to `x` over 1 second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just tween it yourself?

```
float x = 0f;

IEnumerator TweenLinerenderer()
{
    while(x <= 1f)
    {
        myLineRenderer.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(x, 0, 0));
        x += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
    x = 0f;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to use DOTween to save code but I guess you can't do it. This works though, thanks.

Comment: not a really good answer... Dotween has a lot of options like Easing and other tools that you should implement on your own otherwise,.

Answer (score 2):

```
LineRenderer l = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
DOTween.To(() => l.GetPosition(lineRenderPoint), (x) => l.SetPosition(lineRenderPoint, x), new Vector3(0, 0, 10), 10).Play();
```

Where `lineRenderPoint` is the point you want to move.